# Nested-associations in node js with restful-sequelize and mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest, express, sequelize.js

I am trying to build restful-apis in node js using restful-sequelize and express. 
I am having two tables, Category and Product. I want my get url for Categories to return the Category with the list of products associated with it. 
For e.g. /api/categories should return -

```
 [{"category_id":1,"name":"kids", "products":[/*list of products*/]}]
```

How can I do that? Examples would be of great help.

I think maybe my relations are not defined correctly, or I need to modify the findAll() method. 
My code is as follows:

```
var express   = require('express')
  , bodyParser = require('body-parser')
  , Sequelize = require('sequelize')
  , http      = require('http')
  , Restful   = require('new-sequelize-restful')
  , sequelize = new Sequelize('test', 'root', 'root', {
        logging: console.log,
        define: {
            timestamps: false
        }
    })
  , app       = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.use(bodyParser());

var Category = sequelize.define('categories', {
    category_id: {type:Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey:true},
    name: Sequelize.STRING
}); 

var Product = sequelize.define('products', {
    product_id: {type:Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey:true},
    name: Sequelize.STRING,
    description: Sequelize.STRING,
    price: Sequelize.FLOAT,
    categoryCategoryId: Sequelize.INTEGER
});

// Relationship definition
Category.hasMany(Product, {as:'products'});

app.all(/\/api\//, (new Restful(sequelize)).route());
app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
```

Comment: Maybe look at the examples on the github page of the library you're using?  https://github.com/blekr/new-sequelize-restful

Answer (score 0):

Which I myself resolved as follows:
    First fix assocation:

```
Category.hasMany(Product, {
as: 'products',
foreignKey: 'categoryCategoryId'});
```

Then:

```
Category.findAll({
include: [{
    model: Product,
    'as': 'products' //because you rename model Product on association with Category
}]}).then(function(response) {
console.log(response)}, function(err) {
console.log(err)});
```